# User defaults using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2

So, I hope I'm asking this correctly. I would like to add defaults to my web application. So when a user changes the default number of rows in a table the app will remember this and then next time the user logs in they will get 25 rows instead on 15; as an example.

Are there any libraries that can help add this kind of support. I want it to be seamless.

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking `LocalStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Answer (score 2):

To make this works you have below two options

1. If the defaults to be only during the current session then you can manage with local storage of HTML5 like `localStorage.setItem("defaults", "25");` this will be cleared once the window is closed.
2. If the defaults to be maintained anytime even if the users log out, it's better to store the customer table in the backend and you can load the number of defaults values from the DB and display the records

Comment: Cool. I guess I want the settings to go with the user. So I'll need to find some way to save changes to the settings in the background.